# Бот. Одушевленное или нет?

Tags: одушевленность

Встретил предложение:

*Мы сделали в Telegram новый бот*

Правильное ли оно? Бот в данном значении должен быть одушевлённым или нет?

Answer (score 1):

В обычном употреблении это такой же *неодушевленный* программный продукт (элемент) как вирус (ср.: "написать вирус"). Среди материальных объектов подобное положение занимает "*робот*": до тех пор, пока его специально не одушевят (человекоподобные роботы, роботы-собаки и т. п.), он грамматически остается неодушевленным - это всего лишь усложнённая разновидность *манипулятора*. С вашим ботом одушевление может произойти в случае, если вы его визуализируете на экране как человечка (или как иное живое существо) и будете ссылаться на его игровой образ. В техническом же контексте (при обсуждении его назначения и функций) тот же самый "бот" будет грамматически неодушевленым.

Answer (score 1):

> *Правильное ли оно?*

Да.

> Бот в данном значении должен быть одушевлённым или нет?*

Обе формы возможны, но тут скорее неодушевленность.

Слово "бот" (в айтишной сфере) испытывает колебание в категории одушевленности. Такое случается, причем не только с относительно новыми словами, но и в силу особых причин и правил употребления.

Alex_ander достаточно подробно изложил ситуацию с упомянутым колебанием, но упустил из виду одну существенную деталь. Все это общие слова, которые применимы к любому объекту.

Но, во-первых, бот становится одушевленным не в силу того, что он выглядит, как человечек, а в силу того, что он имитирует поведение разумного существа. 
***За время стажировки в фирме "Вязаные веники" студент Такой Сякоевич Разэтакий разрабатывал программных ботов по заданию заказчика.*** Неужели у кого-то повернется язык или рука в такой конструкции употребить неодушевленную форму?!

И вторая причина. Слово "бот" очень похоже по своим свойствам на слово "робот" (собственно, в английском "бот" и появилось из "робота" отсечением первого слога). Так вот, "робот" почти всегда одушевлен (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords?layout=item&id=25_181) - и это закреплено словарями. Видимо, со временем и слово *бот* станет одушевленным (пусть и не в такой мере, как "робот").

Но это все рассуждения, несколько выходящие за рамки непосредственно вопроса.
Ваш пример, как уже сказал, вполне правилен и в данном контексте - предпочтителен.

Comment: В целом согласен, но выделенный полужирным пример неудачен. Нужно заменить "участвовал в разработке" на "разрабатывал" (чтобы вместо родительного использовался винительный падеж) и станет видно, что "разрабатывал программные боты" звучит вполне допустимо (как и "одушевлённый" вариант).

Comment: Разумность тоже не существенная характеристика — важно, что  у него есть какое-то поведение.

Comment: *Разумность тоже не существенная характеристика — важно, что у него есть какое-то поведение.* - как сказать... поведение есть  у шарика, скатывающегося по наклонной поверхности. Но оно не разумно. Но я не буду это педалировать. Как говорится "на защиту не выносится".

Comment: *но выделенный полужирным пример неудачен* - не против. Спасибо. Кажется, я изначально так и собирался написать, да потом что-то перемудрил.